# How to send the data from one xml to another xml layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

1.First `Activity` : 
  This `Activity` has two `EditTexts` and two `Buttons`.
  I need to give login id and password.Here
the `Buttons` contained logging in and cancel:

```
package com.samelayout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class SameLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText Myusername;
    EditText Mypassword;
    Button btnlogin;
    Button btncancel;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnlogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        btncancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
        Myusername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        Mypassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);    
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {           public void onClick(View v) {
                String str1=Myusername.getText().toString();
                String str2=Mypassword.getText().toString();
                Intent int1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
                Bundle b= new Bundle();
                b.putString("userdata", str1);
                b.putString("userdata1", str2);
                int1.putExtras(b);
                int1.putExtras(b);
                //(int1);
                startActivityForResult(int1, 0);
            }
        });
    btncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });  
    }
}
```

2.second `Activity`:
This `Activity` retrieves the data from the first `Activity`. I need to show user details to second xml file

```
package com.samelayout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Login extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        //Intent int1= getIntent();
        Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(b!=null)
        {
            String str1=b.getString("userdata");
            String str2=b.getString("userdata1");
            TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
            TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
            tv1.setText(str1);
            tv2.setText(str2);
            setContentView(tv1);
            setContentView(tv2); }
    } }
```

3.`main.xml` here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Linearlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:text="Employee ID:" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#0000FF" 
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText android:hint="enter ur ID" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/username"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:text="Password:" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#0000FF" 
        android:textSize="20dip"/>

        <EditText android:singleLine="true" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/password" 
        android:password="true"/>

        <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Submit" 
        android:id="@+id/loginbutton"/>

        <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Cancel" 
        android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"/>
      </LinearLayout>
```

4.needed output can be displayed here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Linearlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Employee Name:" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#0000FF" 
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:text="Employee password:" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#0000FF" 
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

5.this is my Logcat getting errors

```
11-22 12:04:27.298: W/KeyCharacterMap(334): No keyboard for id 0
11-22 12:04:27.298: W/KeyCharacterMap(334): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-22 12:04:37.738: D/AndroidRuntime(334): Shutting down VM
11-22 12:04:37.738: W/dalvikvm(334): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.samelayout/com.samelayout.Login}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.samelayout.SameLayoutActivity$1.onClick(SameLayoutActivity.java:41)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-22 12:04:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 12:04:42.079: I/Process(334): Sending signal. PID: 334 SIG: 9
11-22 14:46:39.458: W/KeyCharacterMap(377): No keyboard for id 0
11-22 14:46:39.458: W/KeyCharacterMap(377): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-22 14:46:42.309: D/AndroidRuntime(377): Shutting down VM
11-22 14:46:42.309: W/dalvikvm(377): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.samelayout/com.samelayout.Login}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at com.samelayout.SameLayoutActivity$1.onClick(SameLayoutActivity.java:38)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-22 14:46:42.329: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 14:48:22.648: D/AndroidRuntime(411): Shutting down VM
11-22 14:48:22.648: W/dalvikvm(411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.samelayout/com.samelayout.Login}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at com.samelayout.SameLayoutActivity$1.onClick(SameLayoutActivity.java:38)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-22 14:48:22.657: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 14:59:44.668: W/KeyCharacterMap(441): No keyboard for id 0
11-22 14:59:44.668: W/KeyCharacterMap(441): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-22 14:59:53.378: D/AndroidRuntime(441): Shutting down VM
11-22 14:59:53.388: W/dalvikvm(441): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.samelayout/com.samelayout.Login}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.samelayout.SameLayoutActivity$1.onClick(SameLayoutActivity.java:38)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-22 14:59:53.411: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 15:04:53.512: I/Process(441): Sending signal. PID: 441 SIG: 9
```

6.android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samelayout"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SameLayoutActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name=".Login" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Also, Change the question its something like to misunderstanding for other users.

Comment: Put the username details to SharedPreferences and access from any activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **SameLayoutActivity** replace this,

```
 btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {           public void onClick(View v) {
                String str1=Myusername.getText().toString();
                String str2=Mypassword.getText().toString();
                Intent int1=new Intent(SameLayoutActivity.this,Login.class);
                Bundle b= new Bundle();
                b.putString("userdata", str1);
                b.putString("userdata1", str2);
                int1.putExtras(b);
                //(int1);
                startActivityForResult(int1, 0);
            }
        });
```

In your **Login Activity**, Replace this code, And try again and let me know what happen ..

```
  TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
  TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
if(b!=null)
        {
            String str1=b.getString("userdata");
            String str2=b.getString("userdata1");

            tv1.setText(str1);
            tv2.setText(str2);
            }
    }
```

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SameLayoutActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login"> </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your data through the `Intent` used to start the 2nd Activity. Check this [blog post](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-pass-data-to-activity.html) out.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily by data binding by setting

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

inside your Build.gradle(:app)

Now, to send data from one xml to another, look at the below example. In this, I have made a layout named item_top_card.xml which I want to include it in another xml file with different titles. One way is to make different xml for different titles. A good way is to pass the title string from one xml to another as shown :

```
<include
   android:id="@+id/todays_clicks_parent"
   app:option="@{@string/todays_clicks}"
   layout="@layout/item_top_card" />
```

You can include the layout xml which you want to include in other xml file as shown above. Notice that here we are passing the string in "option" parameter. This is the parameter name which can be changed as per your needs. Below is the file for item_top_card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="option" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardElevation="0.1dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingVertical="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_circle"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_light"
                android:paddingHorizontal="12dp"
                android:paddingVertical="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/clicks"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:lineHeight="24dp"
                android:text="123"
                android:paddingVertical="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textFontWeight="600"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineHeight="20dp"
                tools:text="@string/todays_clicks"
                android:text="@{option}"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey_text_color"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</layout>
```